# TypeError: on my python Rotation Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, rotation

I want to setup a rotation matrix in python where I can rotate my vectors by 5 degrees:

```
import math

angle = math.radians(5)
#define sine
sine = math.sin
#define cosine
cosine = math.cos
#rotation matrix
rotMatrix = array([[cosine(angle), -sine(angle)],
                  [sine(angle),  cosine(angle)]])
```

however when I run my program i get an error at my rotMatrix

```
TypeError: must be unicode character, not list
```

It errors on the following line:

```
rotMatrix = array([[cosine(angle), -sine(angle)],
                  [sine(angle),  cosine(angle)]])
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong to get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
sin = math.sin(angle)
cos = math.cos(angle)
```

to:

```
sin = math.sin
cos = math.cos
```

The error was that you were trying to call `sin(...)` after you have declared `sin` as a float (`math.sin(angle)` returns a float)

**Edit**

I will recommend you using `numpy.array` instead of `array.array` because it seems that creating an array of lists is not possible.

Or simpler, use a list of lists like:

```
rotMatrix = [[a, b, c],
             [d, e, f],
             [g, h, i]]
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense i changed my code and now i am getting a new error see corrections in post

Comment: Show more than that please, you are assigning it to a variable?

Comment: i am assigning it to rotMatrix

Comment: Also, please don't modify your post with the correct answers, because the goal of this site is to help everybody with a similar problem. Next time, create another instead.

Comment: I tested the code, and it's working. The problem may not be there. Can you post the entire error trace? And, I'm assuming array is `numpy.array`, isn't it?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "<module2>", line 24, in <module>
TypeError: must be a unicode character, not list

Comment: You could read http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html documentation. Also I will recommend you using `numpy` library, since it seems that you can't create an array of Lists in the way you are trying.

Answer (score 2):

You assigned the name `sin` to `math.sin(angle)`.  `sin` is now a number, the sine of 5 degrees.  When you try to call `sin(angle)`, you are trying to call a number.  The same is true for `cos`.  Change your matrix to use `sin` and `cos` instead of `sin(angle)` and `cos(angle)`.  Or, probably a better idea, name those variables something like `sinA` and `cosA`.  It's confusing to have a function called `sin` and a variable called `sin` that is the sine of a particular angle.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense so i have changed my code and now i am getting a new error see corrections in post